# CSS "bouncing" line inside screen animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a cool idea, but I'm kinda stuck on how to achieve this.

This is a tutorial on creating a bouncing ball animation:
[Bouncing ball animation tutorial](http://www.cssnewbie.com/pure-css-bouncing-ball/#.UWZ6XKvUaFc)

I would like to create something similar but with a worm-like line. The line faces the direction it's going and changes direction as it hits the wall.

I guess there are two parts to this which I can't figure out:

1. How do I make the line face the direction it's going? Using CSS.
2. How do I get a worm-like directional change as the line reaches the end of the container e.g. screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a guess, you will likely need to use JavaScript as well. Some inspiration here. http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-game-tutorial-make-a-snake-game-using-html5-canvas-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be quite hard to do with CSS only.  The ball is round so when it 'hits' and edge it just bounces off.  A line would bounce off and half-way during the bounce the line would be going in two directions (the portion that has bounced off the wall and the part that has not).  You aren't going to be able to do that easily with just CSS.

To make the line go the direction you want it to you could just use the correct amount of transform: rotate  to make it point the same direction it is moving.  Again this would work and would look good until the line runs into a wall.

Comment: Thanks Femker, now you've got me thinking... I understand now that a CSS only solution isn't possible. Thanks :)